# How do I center an image and give it 100% of window height, and have dynamically-resizing images around it?

Tags: html, css

We want to display an image like this centred in a page: the height should be 100% of the window height, with corresponding proportional width. On either side of the image, we'd like to continue the grey brick pattern that you see at top and bottom of the image across the page on either side. The background should match the size of, and line up with, the one in the image, however big the image is.

Can anyone suggest a CSS-only way to do this?

[image]

Here's the kind of markup I've been trying so far:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://i.metro.co.uk/images/temp/visual.png" id="middle">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(visual-top.png) repeat-x;
}

#middle {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/andfinally/pen/jHbys).

Comment: Have you taken any stabs at this?  Do you need this to work for only specific browsers?

Comment: Help us help you; what have you tried so far/what code do you have?

Comment: Could you post your current code and/or a JS Fiddle please.

Comment: I would make the brick pattern separate, repeat it, and place the image however I want with a black background filling empty space

Comment: My apologies, I'll sort out an example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. You might run into aliasing-problems so that your images don't line up perfectly, but in theory it's easy.

The way I would do it is using multiple backgrounds. Here is the CSS you need:

```
body {
    background: url([screenshot.jpg]) center top no-repeat, url([tile.jpg]) center top repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 100%, auto 17.5%;
}
```

Then you need to fiddle with the height of the tile. I came up with 17.5%, but that depends on your screenshot.

[Here is a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nquuejde/)

Comment: Per that is a beautiful solution! I salute you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="brick">

</div>
<div id="mario">

</div>
```

css

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#brick{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:gray;
    background-image: url(brick.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    top:0;left:0;
    z-index: -1;
}
#mario{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image:url(mario.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks avril, but that doesn't work for me - the mario image fills the window height but the background bricks stay a constant height. Per's solution looks like the one to me.

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done.

```
<div class="wrapper"><img src="yourimage.jpg"/></div>
```

the css

```
.wrapper{
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align: center;
}
.wrapper img{
height:100%;
z-index:1;
}
```

So it will be on top of your background

Comment: You need to make your answers more readable, like putting the code in the right format and also making the answer more eligible or you will get loads of down votes.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <img src="path/to/img.jpg"/>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper .top{
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: url('pattern.jpg') 0 0 repeat;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.wrapper img{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danis, but with this solution I get the same kind of problem I do with avril's - the relative sizes of the pattern and the image don't match.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<style>
.main{
   width:100%;
   display:table;
   text-align:center;
   height: "image-height";
}
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>

<div class="main">
 <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="image.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
</body>

You can try this. This is nice article.
```